# Linebreaks rendering differently in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am utilizing the 960 CSS grid system. I was making a really quick mock up of a website and noticed that my line breaks were rendering quite differently in chrome than they were in IE8.

The following link has screenshots of both browsers. The first image is IE8 and the second is Chrome: http://imgur.com/YLgcsl&kIeTn

**What can I do to rid my code of inconsistencies**

Here is the code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>The 1Kb Grid Demo – 16 columns, 60 pixels each, with 20 pixel gutter</title>
    <link href="grid.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        body { margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
        p {
            font:60px/100px Helvetica;
            color: #000;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        }

        label {
            float:left;
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_16"><p>16</p></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_8">

    <label>First name: </label><br /> <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
    <label>Last name: </label><br />  <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
    <label>ID: </label><br />    <input type="text" name="employnum"/>
    <br />


    <label>Observer</label><br />
    <select style="width:150px" name="observer">
    <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
        <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
        <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>

    </select>

    <label>Observed</label>
    <form action="">
    <select style="width:150px" name="observed">
    <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
    <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select><br />


    <label>Operation Code</label><br />
    <select  style="width:150px"  name="opcode">
                        <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
            <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
            <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>
                        <option value="TEST"> TEST </option>




                    </select>

                    <label>Center</label><br /><br />
                    <select style="width:150px" name="cost">

                        <option value="Zone 1"> Zone 1 </option>
                        <option value="Zone 2"> Zone 2 </option>
                        <option value="Zone 3"> Zone 3 </option>
                    </select>
                    </form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column grid_4"><p>4</p></div>
            <div class="column grid_4"><p>4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column grid_8"><p style="line-height: 222px;">8</p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Browsers (User Agents in general) apply a predefined style on HTML elements. To cancel those predefined styles, designers and developers are encouraged to use resets.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? The only difference I see at a glance is the width of of the dropdown lists are different. Try setting a fixed width on your `select` elements via css.